# Better Code for Comparing Multiple Opps and All Their Products?

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, loop

Trying to compare all Opps and their OLIs to see if there are duplicates (Opps with certain data that is the same, and all OLIs have same product and quantity) and then mark them as potential duplicates. Trickier than it sounds, I'm getting close but comparing all the OLI's is a tricky thing, appreciate thoughts.

```
ID [] FilteredOppIDs = new List<ID>();
                
        for(Opportunity Opp: Opps){            
                
            Opportunity OldOpp = OldOpps.get(Opp.Id);
                                  
            if(Opp.End_Address__c != null && 
               Opp.CloseDate != null &&
               
              (Opp.End_Address__c != OldOpp.End_Address__c || Opp.CloseDate != OldOpp.CloseDate)){
            
                FilteredOppIDs.add(Opp.ID); 
            }
        }  
            
        if(!FilteredOppIDs.isEmpty()){

            Opportunity [] UpdatedOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
            
            String [] EUOAddys = new List<String>();
            Date [] CloseDates = new List<Date>();       
            
            for(Opportunity UpdatedOpp: [SELECT End_Address__c, CloseDate, RecordType.Name, (SELECT OpportunityID, Product2Id, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                                          FROM Opportunity
                                          WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Deal'     
                                          AND ID IN :FilteredOppIDs]){            
                    
                if(UpdatedOpp.OpportunityLineItems != null){
                    
                    EUOAddys.add(UpdatedOpp.End_Address__c);
                    CloseDates.add(UpdatedOpp.CloseDate);                                  
                  
                    UpdatedOpps.add(UpdatedOpp); 
                }
                  
            }     
            
            Opportunity [] OppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
            
            for(Opportunity ExistingOpp: [SELECT End_Address__c, CloseDate, (SELECT OpportunityID, Product2Id, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                                          FROM Opportunity 
                                          WHERE End_Address__c IN :EUOAddys
                                          AND CloseDate IN :CloseDates
                                          AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Deal'] ){
                                            
                for(Opportunity UpdatedOpp: UpdatedOpps){ 
                   
                    //if two different Opp's data and # of OLI's match, then compare their individual products
                    if(UpdatedOpp.ID != ExistingOpp.ID &&
                       UpdatedOpp.End_Address__c == ExistingOpp.End_Address__c &&
                       UpdatedOpp.CloseDate == ExistingOpp.CloseDate &&
                       ExistingOpp.OpportunityLineItems.size() == UpdatedOpp.OpportunityLineItems.size()
                      ){
                                                                                          
                        for(OpportunityLineItem OLIExist : ExistingOpp.OpportunityLineItems){  
                            Boolean ThisOLIHasMatch;                                                                 
                            for(OpportunityLineItem OLIUpdate : UpdatedOpp.OpportunityLineItems){  
                                if(OLIExist.Product2Id == OLIUpdate.Product2Id ||
                                   OLIExist.Quantity == OLIUpdate.Quantity){
                                   OLIsMatch = true; 
   
                                   .....????????
    
                                }    
                            
                            }                          
                        }
                
                     }
                }           
            }
            
            try{
                update OppsToUpdate;
            }        
            catch(DMLexception e){
                system.debug('Error in IdentifyDupeOpps: '+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's usually not a good idea to use an SObject as the key of a Map (or as the datatype of a Set), one really good use case for that is in doing equality checking for multiple pieces of data.

Sets and Maps (well, the keyset of the map) hash the data they're given. Assuming that you don't run into any hash collisions, if `myMap.containsKey()` or `mySet.contains()` return true, then you know that the SObject is an exact match for all of the fields populated *in memory*. Hashing things is a really fast operation, and it takes basically no code.

We can take that one step further, and make it work for an SObject with child records. Instead of a `Set<SObject>`, we can build a `Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>` (the `Map<SObject, List<SObject>>` having the parent record as the key, and the list of child records as the value).

Specifically separating the parent and child records there is important, because queries (and parent-child subqueries) will *always* return the record ids, even if you don't explicitly query for them. Any difference will cause the hash to be different, and Ids are guaranteed to be unique within a single org.

Provided that your queries to find updateOpps and ExistingOpps (and their OLIs) are correct, you'd build the hash-comparator like so

```java
Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>> updateOppSet = new Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>();

for(updateOpps){
    Map<SObject, List<SObject>> oppToLineItems = new Map<SObject, List<SObject>>();
    List<SObject> lineItemList = new List<SObject>();

    // We need to remove not only the Id from the Opp, but also the embedded List
    //   of OLIs that you queried for.
    // If it were just removing the Id, SObject.clone() would be sufficient.
    // Handling the embedded list is the issue.
    // The easy way out is to simply construct our SObject key manually
    // Once you construct oppKey, you should never modify the same instance
    //   of that Opp.
    // Modification would change the hash, and then you'd lose the ability to retrieve
    //   data from the set
    // Creating a completely new instance of an Opportunity in each loop iteration
    //   like we're doing here is fine.
    Opportunity oppKey = new Opportunity(
        End_Address__c = opp.End_Address__c,
        CloseDate = opp.CloseDate,
        RecordType = new RecordType(Name = 'Deal')
    );

    // The only thing we need to get rid of for the OLIs is the Id (as long
    //   as you don't query for OpportunityId as well), so clone() should work fine
    for(OLIs){
        lineItemList.add(oli.clone(false, false, false, false));
    }

    // Waiting til the end here to populate the map means we aren't
    //   calling .get() multiple times via the OLI loop
    // It saves a little cpu time, but more importantly it saves typing.
    oppToLineItems.put(oppKey, lineItemSet);

    updateOppSet.add(oppToLineItems);
}
```

You'll still need to keep track of the encountered End_Address__c and CloseDate values to filter your existingOpp query (might aid in selectivity, will aid in keeping the number of query rows down).

When you loop over `existingOpps`, it'll largely be the same procedure as we used to generate `updateOppSet`. The difference being that instead of adding to `updateOppSet`, you'll be using `contains([Map<SObject, List<SObject>> for existingOpp here])`.

If you want to go further and include the Ids of the potential duplicate opps, the `Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>` can be a `Map<Map<SObject, List<SObject>, Id>` (or `List<Id>`) instead.

The comparison doesn't really care if you build the Set with the existing opps, or the opps being updated, but since I imagine you want to set the potential duplicate flag on the opps being updated, you should query/iterate over the existing opps first.

```
for(triggered opps){
  check if it's something you want to process further
    if so, add the end address and close date to your lists
}

for(existing opps (query using the end address and close date lists)){
    build the Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>
}

for(update opps (query using the end address and close date lists again)){
    build a Map<SObject, List<SObject>>
    check if it exists in the Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>
      if so, use the Id of the opp loop variable to find the opp instance in trigger.newMap, and set your potential duplicate flag
}
```

#### +edit:

It's worth noting that `new List<String>{'a' ,'b'} != new List<String>{'b',a'}`.

Lists are ordered, and thus order matters. This also appears to be baked into checking equality through hashcodes. Even though they will print out the same hashcode (4096 for me), `(new List<String>{'a' ,'b'}).hashcode() != (new List<String>{'b','a'}).hashcode()`

To get around this issue, you can either:

- Call `.sort()` on the `List<SObject>` before putting it into the Map
- Use a `Set<SObject>` instead, making the overall data structure a `Set<Map<SObject, Set<SObject>>`

Comment: "While it's usually not a good idea to use an SObject as the key of a Map" I would disagree, at least not without qualification. If a given data type is the correct type to use, I would use it. Comparing multiple fields easily is definitely a good use.

Comment: Thanks for this @Derek F, good ideas, especially the cloning. One thing I don't follow - why use Set<Map<SObject, List<SObject>> for the existing opps loop, instead of just Map<SObject, List<SObject>>?

Comment: @number41 Because you're trying to compare both the Opp and its OLIs. Sticking the whole thing into a `Set` means you hash/compare the contents of the `Map` (key and values) as one, and in a single operation.

Comment: @Derek F Ah, I see, hence the idea of using "contains()" against the Set. My only worry about constructing the objects myself is the order of the elements - if two Opps with identical OLIs are compared, how can I know that the OLIs in each list will be in the same order, and hence considered identical? I know if you compare two lists like (a, b) and (b, a), they will be considered different because their elements are in a different order,

Comment: @number41 That's...actually a good point. I didn't think it would matter, but it turns out that it does. In that case, using a `Set<Map<SObject, Set<SObject>>>` or calling`.sort()` on the `List<SObject>` before putting it into the map should work. Looks like I'll be editing my answer.